# Recognize HTML tags with PHPWord

Tags: php, html, phpword

Is there a way that I can get PHPWord to reconize HTML tags. I don't need the more complicated once, just `<strong>` and `<em>`. If there is not a function or library that I can use for this any ideas about how to bold `<strong>` and italicize `<em>` tags would be great to hear.

Comment: You use PHPWord's text runs to set blocks of text to bold or italic: there is no facility built in to convert from HTML markup

Comment: it's not phpworld's job to parse/render html. You can easily do `->addText('slanted', array('italic' => true))` yourself.

Comment: What do you do though when only certain words in a string are bold?

Comment: You write an addText() run for each block of code with its own styling

Comment: Well the problem with that is that I need certain words in a sentence bold and using addText() puts it on a new line. The string looks something like this: "this is a <strong> string </strong> that needs some words <strong> BOLD </strong> and some not!". Is there any way to have the certain words in it bold?

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to use PHP Word to recognize HTML documents and transform them into Word docs. Unfortunately, it didn't do a great job, because things like images didn't work correctly.

I ended up going with another solution that's much more full-featured, [PHPDocX](http://www.phpdocx.com/). It does cost between $100 and $400, but it had great HTML-to-Word support.

Comment: Images will work correctly if they're handled correctly by the code you've written to convert the HTML markup to call PHPWord methods

Answer (score 0):

In current version (0.13) you can use:

```
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $htmlString);
```

It support the most common basic tags.
You can see a full example here: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_26_Html.php